# Mutual authentication - Timeouts on port 8443

Tags: ssl, api-client-certificate

I am getting started on the Mutual Authentication certificates. I have followed the documentation and set up the **Enforce TLS/SSL** and **API Only** system properties for the profile. I have logged in without the port 8443 and was testing this on curl:

```
curl -vk https://cs14.salesforce.com:8443/services/Soap/u/45.0 -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8" -H "SOAPAction: example" -d @getuserinfo.xml -E full_cert.pem
```

However, this gives out

> Failed to connect to cs14.salesforce.com port 8443: Timed out

I have also noticed that the

```
curl -vk https://cs14.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/45.0 -H "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8" -H "SOAPAction: example" -d @getuserinfo.xml
```

fails with

> MUTUAL_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED: This session could not be mutually authenticated for use with the API

Can anyone guide me with how they went about with the timeout errors?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you went through the process of opening a case with Salesforce to first get this feature enabled?

Comment: Yes, all the pre-requisites are setup but I'm having trouble connecting to port 8443. Does this have to do anything with the certificates that is uploaded for Mutual Authentication?

Comment: No it shouldn't. Are you on a corporate network? Maybe there is a firewall preventing communication on that port.

Comment: Yes, it was blocked on the corporate network. Thanks for that suggestion :)